# Python importing hierarchy failing

Tags: python, import, python-import, hierarchy, relative-path

```
server
├── rhino
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
├── web
│   ├── main.py
```

That is my structure, there are other files but they should not intervene.

In `main.py` I have the following import:

`from ..rhino import Rhino`

That should work, given there is a `Rhino` class in the `app.py` file.

Yet for some reason I get this error?
`attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I'm utterly confused.

Comment: I guess creating an `__init__.py` in `web` and `server` should solve the problem.

Comment: A relative import can't go above the root directory (the directory where the start script is located or a directory added to `sys.path` under some circumstances).